# Internet Explorer cannot display index.html in Samba Share

Tags: windows-server-2012, samba, apache-2.4, centos7

I have virtual Centos box with Samba and Apache server installed. I created shared folder in Samba and I am able map that folder via my virtual Windows Server '12. I am able to see and edit files in the samba sahred folder via Windows Explorer in Windows Server.

However, I cannot display index.html via Internet Explorer by typing http : // < net bios name of Apache Server > neither by http : `// < ip address of Apache Server >` . Why does Windows Explorer work but not Internet Explorer?
If I type IE address bar `\\ < net bios name of Apache >` it opens the folder but when I use `http : // < net bios name of Apache >` protocol, it doesn't display the index.html page.

What do I need to get it work?
Thank you

Comment: I forgot to mention that I edited Windows hosts file by adding net bios name and IP address of Samba server.

Answer (score 1):

Because Samba is working and Apache is not.  Samba doesn't serve http, that's apache's job in this situation.   You need to check your apache setup.  Is it running?  Where is the document root pointed?